# Does anyone know a free compiler for Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I want to learn Delphi, does anyone know of a good free program that would let me write code with Delphi?

I want to learn as many languages as I can, I already kinda know C#, some LUA, some VB and Java, but I want to know more. For the sake of knowing I guess.

Comment: Only Delphi let you program in Delphi
If you want something free try Free Pascal.

Comment: Well, I might be too late but Borland has released older Delphi versions (<= D7) for free download. Now, getting to them in this time and age is a whole different story.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use Lazarus [FreePascal](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/).